# Windows Azure sending email via SMTP relay

Tags: azure, smtp, sendgrid

I have a site hosted on Windows Azure and currently I am using SendGrid to send emails.  However, we have Mimecast as our email provider and it is marking all emails received from SendGrid as spam.

Is there a way to use Mimecast as the SMTP Relay service from my Windows Azure application?

Comment: How is your expieriece using send grid? we are planning to buy it. How send grid is different from Microsoft Cloud Infrastructure and Operations (formerly GFS) SMTP Relay Service?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Azure as such does not apply any restriction on the outgoing traffic (beside some bandwidth throttling based on the Size of the VM you are running on, but this quite generous). So in practice you can use `any` SMTP relay service.

Whether you can use Mimecast specifically, you shall turn to Mimecast support or products page. But there is nothing in Azure that would stop you from using this or that service (any service).

And Yes, you can use `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` or any other Smtp Client library to talk to external SMTP Service. Whether that external SMTP Service will accept your connection or not, is not subject to any kind of Azure limitation, but sole decision of the service you chose to use.

Comment: So i can use the System.SMTPClient class to send emails out using the mimecase authentication out from Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You should raise a ticket with SendGrid so they can manage this situation. The reason SendGrid is provided is to precisely avoid your mail being marked as spam. You will be unlikely to see any successful mail delivery if you route SMTP traffic directly from an Azure host to a receiving SMTP server.